# Why is sql not letting me create this table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.5

I'm trying to migrate a db 
from: MySQL Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) 
to: MySQL 5.5.4, UNIX

I tried importing the db as a zip package and it started throwing errors so now I'm trying to re-create each table one at a time on phpMyAdmin.

The query below is throwing a #1064 Syntax error, and I'm having trouble figuring out the issue.

MySQL Said:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2),
  `st' at line 6
```

I'm looking at line 6, trying to find any reserved words, missing data, typos, and or obsolete commands but no luck.

```
CREATE TABLE `tblmoto_auth_policies` (
  `policy_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `policy_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `policy_desc` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `policy_url` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` smallint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`policy_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I could use some help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a column as timestamp in MySql workbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608264/setting-a-column-as-timestamp-in-mysql-workbench) While the question is not exactly identical, it looks like it's answer could point to the source of your issue. Specifically, _"Before MySQL 5.6, MySQL did not support fractional seconds stored as part of a TIMESTAMP datatype."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in SQL Fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblmoto_auth_policies` (
  `policy_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `policy_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `policy_desc` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `policy_url` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` smallint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`policy_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

i.e., remove the precision (the `(2)`) from the definition of the `date_added` column.

`TIMESTAMP(2)` is valid syntax, but not in combination with the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` nor `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` auto-initializers.

Answer (score 1):

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is not good

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblmoto_auth_policies` (
  `policy_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `policy_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `policy_desc` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `policy_url` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2),
  `status` smallint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`policy_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Hi Olivier, thanks for your reply. I tried that but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Really !? The issue to me was the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not being at the right format. I just tried it on a mysql 5.7.19 and it's working fine

Comment: @varcxxDesign What you could do is create the table without all the wanted options for the `date_added` column and then manually add them through phpMyAdmin. Once done you should be able to see the creation syntaxe. That might give you a hint on where the problem is coming from.

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` normally allows a precision, but it's (evidently) not parsed that way when MySQL is parsing the column definition in a `CREATE TABLE` statement; it wants just literally `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and/or `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: ... what I said might no longer be true as-of MySQL 5.7; if you seeing something different, then support for this has been added; OP is using 5.5 and SQLFiddle offers 5.6; the version differences probably explain why your solution works for you

Comment: Thank you both! I couldn't have figured it out without your help.